# Printing a new line in a file, in Java

Tags: java, cross-platform, newline, carriage-return, separator

I aim to make an index of all files with a particular extension and store it into index.txt. I am getting all the right results but not getting the 'files' onto the new line, this is a snapshot of my code:

```
OutputStream f0 = new FileOutputStream("index.txt");
    String ind[] = f.list(only); // logic for getting only relevant files
        for(int i=0;i<ind.length;i++)
        {
            File n = new File(path + "/" +ind[i]);
                System.out.println(ind[i]+ " is a " +exten +" file");
                ind[i]+="\n";           // doesnt work      
                f0.write(ind[i].getBytes());    // here i am writing the filenames                              
        }
```

is it due to the getBytes() function which overlooks the "/n" ? Please tell me what to do. I want to insert a new line everytime i exit the for loop.

One major edit: I am getting the desired result when I open the file with notepad++ or wordpad, but when i open the file with notepad i am getting the results on the same line. Please Explain this too!

Comment: can anyone explain the anomaly with the various results i am getting of the same file?

Comment: notepad only reads one type line separator. That's why, it seems to be all in one line.

Comment: @Purushottam "_can anyone explain the anomaly with the various results i am getting of the same file?_" Please have a look at my answer below for a clarification concernint newlines/carriagereturns across platforms.

Answer (score 5):

Try writing:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

instead of \n

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an FileOutputStream I'd use a PrintWriter.

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("index.txt");
String ind[] = f.list(only); // logic for getting only relevant files
for(int i=0;i<ind.length;i++)
{
    File n = new File(path + "/" +ind[i]);
    System.out.println(ind[i]+ " is a " +exten +" file");
    out.println(ind[i]);   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you are working at such a low level of I/O in Java? First of all you should be using Writers instead of OutputStreams.

And then if you use PrintWriter you can do away with the getBytes piece:

PrintWriter f0 = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("index.txt"));

And then later...

f0.print(ind[i]);

And finally to your question, outside the loop simply

f0.println();

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing assumption here.

1. If you assume that your text file should have *MS Windows* line separators (meant for Windows platforms), then you should use `\r\n`.
2. If you assume that your text file should have *Unix-like* line separators (meant for GNU/Linux, AIX, Xenix, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, etc.), then you should use `\n`.
3. If you assume that your text file should have *Mac oldschool* line separators (meant for Mac OS up to version 9, Apple II family, OS-9, etc.), then you should use `\r`.
4. If you assume that your text file should have line separators of the kind of the platform your program is **run** from, then you should use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` (or print the new line with a `.println()`).

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
FileWriter.write("\r\n");
```

Comment: Which is obviously only correct on Windows like platforms and certainly not what you want on Mac or *nix..